# Login page html and javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making a login page.
code:

```js
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");

function validate_login() {
loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = loginForm.username.value;
    const password = loginForm.password.value;

    if (username === "user" && password === "web_dev") {
        window.location.href="https://airtable.com"
    } 
    else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})}
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
}

#main-holder {
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px black;
}

#login-error-msg-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#login-error-msg {
  width: 23%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8a0000;
  border: 1px solid #8a0000;
  background-color: #e58f8f;
  opacity: 0;
}

#error-msg-second-line {
  display: block;
}

#login-form {
  align-self: flex-start;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.login-form-field::placeholder {
  color: #3a3a3a;
}

.login-form-field {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3a3a3a;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

#login-form-submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <main id="main-holder">
    <h1 id="login-header">Login</h1>
    
    <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
      <p id="login-error-msg">Invalid username <span id="error-msg-second-line">and/or password</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <form id="login-form">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-form-submit" onclick="validate_login()">
    </form>
  
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

The css (I showed it because it shows text if the logins are incorrect but it doesn't work) and html work fine but the javascript doesn't work. I am not sure why nothing happens when I press the submit button but I should get an alert. The javascript should check the username and password and then relocate the page.Any help is great. Thanks!!

Comment: You're creating an event handler *after* you click the button, as well as every time you click the button. Get rid of `onclick="validate_login()"` and the function (but keep its contents). _"when I press the submit button but I should get an alert"_ I also see no code that would do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As j08691 explained in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166154/login-page-html-and-javascript-not-working#comment125798226_71166154), your click event handler is creating the event listener after the first click. Instead you should simply create the event listener by removing `function validate_login() {` and the corresponding `}`, and remove the `onclick` attribute in the HTML.

```js
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");

loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = loginForm.username.value;
    const password = loginForm.password.value;

    if (username === "user" && password === "web_dev") {
        window.location.href="https://airtable.com"
    } 
    else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
}

#main-holder {
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px black;
}

#login-error-msg-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#login-error-msg {
  width: 23%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8a0000;
  border: 1px solid #8a0000;
  background-color: #e58f8f;
  opacity: 0;
}

#error-msg-second-line {
  display: block;
}

#login-form {
  align-self: flex-start;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.login-form-field::placeholder {
  color: #3a3a3a;
}

.login-form-field {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3a3a3a;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

#login-form-submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <main id="main-holder">
    <h1 id="login-header">Login</h1>
    
    <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
      <p id="login-error-msg">Invalid username <span id="error-msg-second-line">and/or password</span></p>
    </div>
    
    <form id="login-form">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-form-submit">
    </form>
  
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```